# Google analytics GA4 - Total Revenue shows 0,00€

Tags: angular, google-analytics, angulartics

[image]In the Reports under events I can detect that the purchase event is being sent successfully, however the total revenue portion appears at 0.00.

The project was developed in angular and I am using the angulartics2 library.
All the other events are being reported.

The code that is being sent is:

```
let galayer:any = [];
galayer.push({
'item_id': this.cart[index].iditem,
'item_name': desc,
'price': pval,
'item_brand': brand,
'quantity': this.cart[index].quantity,
'item_category': cat,
'item_variant': color
});
    this.angulartics2.eventTrack.next({
        action: 'Purchase',
        properties: {
            label: 'Purchase',
            currency: "EUR",
            content_type: 'product_group',
    value: obj.total,
            "event":"Purchase",
            gtmCustom:{
                'ecommerce': {
          'click': undefined,
          'add': undefined,
          'checkout': undefined,
          'detail': undefined,
          'impressions': undefined,
          'remove': undefined,
                    'purchase': {
                        'actionField': {'transaction_id': obj.number, 'currency': 'EUR', 'shipping':this.shippingTotal,'value':obj.total},    // 'detail'
                        'items': galayer,
                     }
                 }
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: All fields are being sent with the respective values, using GTM/GA Debug, I can see that all fields are filled in correctly

Comment: The code is not being sent. You don't send code. You send data. Please show us how the data looks. A screenshot from the network tab should do.

Comment: I added a print of the event Purchase GTM/GA Debug (chrome extension)

Comment: Are you trying to check the total revenue of the events sent at least two days ago?

Comment: yes, but does it take a long time to update?

Comment: well GA normally asks for up to two days for the data to start appearing in aggregated reports. Though usuallly most of the data is there after one day.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246598/discussion-between-daniel-simoes-and-bnazaruk).

Comment: It's been over two days, and nothing yet. GA4 is receiving the events only the total revenue appears at 0.00 €